# How build a string in C# with escape characters

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to build a directory path by injecting a `userID` and `portalID` where needed.

```
string userID = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["userID"];
string portalID = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["portalID"];

// This is the acutal path ---> string folderName = @"C:\DotNetNuke 8.0\Portals\0\Users\017\17\17";
string folderName = "c:\\DotNetNuke 8.0\\Portals\\" + portalID + "\\Users\\0" + userID + "\\" + userID + "\\" + userID;
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(folderName);
// This is what's returned ---> c:\DotNetNuke 8.0\Portals\\Users\0\\
```

Comment: I think you're looking for "verbatim string literals", aka the `@` symbol before the quotation mark. Check the reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/string

Comment: userID and portalID are probably empty. To build paths, look at Path.Combine(…) instead of using string concatination.

Comment: Please read [ask] and explain (in words, not in comments in your code) what you expect to see and what you actually see. Also explain what you have tried. Inspecting your variables using the debugger can help you a lot.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thank you for that.  You are right.  Questions shouldn't be in code comments.  However, the how to ask link does not specify that.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is actually correct. It looks like `portalID` and `userId` are `null` or an empty string `""`. There are easier ways to escape, though - if you use `@"some \ string"`, then the only thing you need to escape is `"` to `""`.

Examples:

```
string userID = "17";
string portalID = "0";
string folderName = "c:\\DotNetNuke 8.0\\Portals\\" + portalID + "\\Users\\0" + userID + "\\" + userID + "\\" + userID;
```

gives

```
c:\DotNetNuke 8.0\Portals\0\Users\017\17\17
```

as does:

```
string folderName = @"c:\DotNetNuke 8.0\Portals\" + portalID + @"\Users\0" + userID + @"\" + userID + @"\" + userID;
```

as does:

```
string folderName = $@"c:\DotNetNuke 8.0\Portals\{portalID}\Users\0{userID}\{userID}\{userID}";
```

Comment: Your second example worked like a charm.  Not clear to me why the \\ didn't do the trick.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

best approach would be to use `Path.Combine` method, like this:

```
string userID = "testuser";
string portalID = "portal";
var path = Path.Combine(@"c:\DotNetNuke 8.0\Portals", portalID, "Users", "0" + userID, userID, userID);

Console.WriteLine(path);
```

Result will be

```
c:\DotNetNuke 8.0\Portals\portal\Users\0testuser\testuser\testuser
```

To find more about `Path.Combine` check [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx).